# Deploy https node express server to host website on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm quite new to this. I have a node-express https server that currently runs locally on my machine. My simple website runs on this https sever and make xmlhttp requests to consume some APIs (as these APIs only accept requests from https endpoint). At the moment I'm using a self signed SSL certificate.

I'd like to deploy the server with html, js files to EC2 and make it accessible to the public. My questions are

1. Can I use AWS Certificate Manager to generate a SSL certificate, and how to use it with node-express server? Can node-express use this SSL certificate on EC2? or do I need to use this SSL certificate with Elastic Beanstalk and ELB?
2. I did some research but the ACM documentation said `an email will be sent to the registered domain owner for each domain name in the certificate request.` I don't have a domain as I plan to have users access my site using IP address. What do I do in this case?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not a great idea to just use a IP, and domains are cheap.  Pony up the $10/year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't use an ACM certificate directly with NodeJS. You have to place a load balancer in front of your server and install the ACM certificate on the load balancer.
2. The ACM service does not support SSL certificates for IP addresses, only domain names. I recommend obtaining a domain name.

Comment: Thanks! So the recommended architecture would be a)  ACM certificate + domain name +load balancer + node-express http (not https server) on EC2 or b) bring my own CA signed SSL+ node-express https server on EC2 using ip address for public acccess ?

Comment: Yes, you've got it. You could use Let's Encrypt for a free SSL cert on your EC2 server if you want to save money by not using a load balancer.

Comment: Thank you! @Mark B One more thing, for testing, I could also c) use a free self signed SSL, assign it to load balancer +Elastic Beanstalk + node-express server on EC2; and have the public access my site using that public DNS address of EC2?  I reckon I'd need to disable Chrome's security "--disable-web-security --user-data-dir"  as the certificate is not signed?

Comment: You can use a self-signed cert if you are OK with browsers blocking your website and forcing all your users to enter your website as an exception to the browser's security rules.